# Type Class with many type parameters

Tags: scala, typeclass

I have function with a few type parameters. How to tell compiler that these types are actually in type class?

```
trait Sizeable[-T, +R] {
  def mySize(x: T): R
}

implicit object StringSize extends Sizeable[String, Int] {
  def mySize(s: String) = s.length
}

def sum[T, R: Sizeable[T, R]](xs: List[T]): R =  xs.map(x => x.mySize)
```

The error is:

```
Error:(9, 14) A$A40.this.Sizeable[T,R] does not take type parameters 
def sum[T, R: Sizeable[T, R]](xs: List[T]): R =  xs.map(x => x.mySize);}
```

Comment: Your `Sizeable` typeclass is a bit silly since both `String` and `Int` are final. So `Sizeable[String,Int]` is the only possible instance of this typeclass.

Comment: And shouldn't your `sum` method look like this instead? `def sum[T, R: Sizeable[T, R]](xs: List[T]): List[R] =  xs.map(x => implicitly[Sizeable[T,R]].mySize(x))`

Comment: Also your `T` and `R` don't respect the type boundaries for your trait, you should edit your question, it's really unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Jasper-M i removed these constraints. Actually i need reacher types, you are right.

Comment: @Jasper-M `def sum[T, R: Sizeable[T, R]](xs: List[T]): List[R] = xs.map(x => implicitly[Sizeable[T,R]].mySize(x))` - these also doesn't compile.

Comment: @EndeNeu I changed constraints, because they are really irrelevant to the question. All i need is to somehow compile the body of `sum` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a context bound in this case. You'll have to write the implicit parameter explicitly:

```
def foo[T, R](xs: List[T])(implicit sizeable: Sizeable[T,R]): List[R] =
  xs.map(x => sizeable.mySize(x))
```

Comment: That is not a context bound, that is an implicit type parameter, but you are right saying that it cannot be used in this case, if  `Sizeable` had taken only one type parameter `T: Sizeable` would have worked fine.

Comment: @EndeNeu This is most certainly a context bound. It's possible to get it to work with multiple type parameters, [http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/5310.html]see Jason Zaugg's response here). It's more trouble than it's worth trying to get it to work with trickery, in my opinion though.

Comment: @m-z  Jason Zaugg's response is helpful. He uses lambdatypes to bound two types together. Pretty sad that Scala doesn't have sugar for multiple types in context bound.

Comment: @m-z I actually thought it was called something different since that only implies that you have an implicit parameter somewhere in scopes and not that the type has a constraint.